# How to plot and save every layer (time) of a array as a image using image.plot and a loop in R programming

Tags: r, loops, plot

I have an array of size 19*15*36. I want to plot and save 36 images using image.plot function in "fields" package.

```
library(fields)

for(k in 1:dim(array)[3]) {
    image.plot(lon, lat, array[,,k])
}
```

Comment: Where is the problem? Do you perhaps want to save images to files? If yes, then try using `png`, `pdf`, `jpg` or some other device. Don't forget to construct a meaningful file name (e.g. using `sprintf`) and close the writing to the device using `dev.off`. See example files in the first three mentioned functions for more details.

Comment: yes i want to save these plots. i gave use these codes also.

Comment: Yes, i want to save these plots. I have use these codes also.                          for(k in 1:dim(array){png('array[k]')
image.plot(lon, lat, array[,,k])
title("array[k]")
dev.off()
}

Comment: It's still not clear where the problem is, then. Please elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

To save images to plots, you first need to construct a proper filename. In this case, I'm using `sprintf`, but you could also use `paste`, for example. See `?jpeg` for more information.

```
for(k in 1:dim(array)[3]) {
  filename <- sprintf("imageplot_%d.jpg", k) # %d gets replaced by the number

  jpeg(filename, width = 800, height = 600) 
  image.plot(lon, lat, array[,,k])
  dev.off()
}
```